# Mark occurance in pycharm not working

Tags: python, pycharm

Like shown below, mark occurance in pycharm not working, it used to work before. stopped working since morning.

[image]

[image]

i have attached settings pic aswell

Comment: Did you perform any update on any of the related software packages? You share very little info on your configuration. This, it will be hard for anyone to help you...

Comment: No i did not, I can provide as much info as u need. Just name it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with deleting the whole config when pycharm is not running.

1. Close Pycharm
2. Delete whole config-folder under `<user-home>\.PyCharm50\`.
3. Start Pycharm -> let pycharm create a new config

Comment: I can't really find this config file or the .PyCharm50 folder either.

Comment: config is a folder itself, are you on windows?
`C:\Users\<myUserName>\.PyCharm50\config` this is the windows default directory

Comment: I Cannot find that folder, but i did find a file called config.py, "C:\app\Tools\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\nose_helper\config.py". does this have to do anything with my pycharm config?

Comment: no, thats not it. As I said `config` is a folder. Sometimes Windows hides folders starting with a dot.

Comment: Reinstalling the program did not help either. i cleared all the caches and left over by pycharm. Still doesnt work.

Comment: After the new installation, did it ask you for your existing config (is normally preselected). Also if you open Pycharm go to `File > Export Settings` the `Export Settings to` File-Path is preselected with your config folder!

Comment: So i delete whole config folder and restart my pycharm? or should i specific files inside that folder?, btw thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95326/discussion-between-altoyr-and-ashok).

Comment: sorry cant access that link from my office.

Comment: ok... 1) close pycharm 2) delete whole config folder 3) start pycharm